# Cannot get a result by Max date

Tags: t-sql, max

I'm trying to get the highlighted result only as it's the latest date. First time I've asked a question here so I apologize in advance if this isn't clear. Thanks

[image: 1]

By using the following query

```
SELECT 
MAX(A.Insp_Date) AS Last_Insp_Date
,A.Doc_ID
,A.Service_Call_ID
,A.Customer_ID
,A.Address_Code
,A.State
,A.Branch
,B.HydLoc
,B.FlwOutSz
,B.StaticPSI
,B.ResidualPSI
,B.PititPSI
,B.FlwGPM


FROM [dbo].[fofHydrntInspHdr] AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[fofHYD2800FlwTstRT] AS B
        ON A.Doc_ID = B.Doc_ID

WHERE A.Doc_ID > 0
AND A.Address_Code = 'GEN0021'        

GROUP BY
A.Doc_ID
,A.Service_Call_ID
,A.Customer_ID
,A.Address_Code
,A.State
,A.Branch
,B.HydLoc
,B.FlwOutSz
,B.StaticPSI
,B.ResidualPSI
,B.PititPSI
,B.FlwGPM
```

I've also tried using max doc_id and it still doesn't work. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option that shouldn't require two scans of your table is to filter for the latest using a window function:

```
with r as
(
    SELECT 
    A.Insp_Date AS Last_Insp_Date
    ,A.Doc_ID
    ,A.Service_Call_ID
    ,A.Customer_ID
    ,A.Address_Code
    ,A.State
    ,A.Branch
    ,B.HydLoc
    ,B.FlwOutSz
    ,B.StaticPSI
    ,B.ResidualPSI
    ,B.PititPSI
    ,B.FlwGPM
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.Insp_Date DESC) AS r

    FROM [dbo].[fofHydrntInspHdr] AS A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[fofHYD2800FlwTstRT] AS B
            ON A.Doc_ID = B.Doc_ID

    WHERE A.Doc_ID > 0
    AND A.Address_Code = 'GEN0021'
)
SELECT  
    Insp_Date AS Last_Insp_Date
    ,Doc_ID
    ,Service_Call_ID
    ,Customer_ID
    ,Address_Code
    ,State
    ,Branch
    ,HydLoc
    ,FlwOutSz
    ,StaticPSI
    ,ResidualPSI
    ,PititPSI
    ,FlwGPM
FROM r
WHERE r = 1;
```

---

As an aside, I would advise against aliasing your tables with `A`, `B`, `C` etc as they don't relate to the table and make understanding the query later on more awkward.  In this case, aliases like `h` and `ft` would convey that one table is the Headers and the other the Flow Tests, whilst also reducing character count.

It also looks like you have some bad duplication going on in your results there, which suggests that either your query is not joining and filtering appropriately or your data is messy.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this actually returned the un-highlighted results exactly as shown in the image above. The duplication is a result of the data changes you see in the right hand columns and yes, it's messy but that data gets generated by real people unfortunately.

Comment: Oh apologies, you just need to add a `desc` to the sort order on the `dense_rank`.  I've updated this above.

Comment: And with regard to the duplication, you will notice that the first 8 rows in your question example are actually the same 4 rows duplicated.  This suggests that either the data is in the flow rates table twice (should be cleaned) or you are missing a `join` criteria.